# "<li>" tags incompatible with current navbar layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

Simply put, I designed and coded a very simple horizontal navbar with HTML and CSS, without using `li` tags, and have now found out that I need a dropdown. No biggie, I'll just add some `li` and some `ul` tags to create it. Nope, doesn't work. It forces the image that I have lying over the navbar down, and completely ignores the CSS I have in place for the links within the div already (obviously, `li` tags have their own styling, don't they?

Currently, this is the HTML:

```
<div id="navside">
<a href="Beds.html">Beds</a>
<a href="Furniture.html">Furniture</a>
<h> Francis of Malvern </h>
<a href="Carpets.html">Flooring</a>
<a href="Clearance.html">Clearance</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#navside {
position: absolute;
color: #ffffff;
width:100%;
height: 15%;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.6);
color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
}

#navside a {
font-size: 20px;
padding-right:100px;
padding-left:100px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navside a:hover {
color: gray;
}
```

code that I'm using for the navbar alone.

Basically, I just want to know if it is possible to get a dropdown to work without messing with the layout of the rest of the page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A JSFiddle link showing the issue would be nice :)

Comment: Please show an example of your HTML with the `li` elements in place.

Comment: I assume you're missing a number after the `<h>` eg `<h1>` etc..?

Comment: Okay, on re-entering the li tags to demonstrate the HTML, the issue seems to have resolved itself. I'm very much new to coding so I was probably just entering tags wrong before, thanks guys and sorry about that